# mysql and python idle connector on Mac installed (pip file and connector from mysql site and the version is right)but on idle the module is not found

Tags: mysql-python, python-idle

pip3 install mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python
I have been able to download succssfully using these [commands][1]
also installed macOS 10.15 (Architecture Independent), DMG Archive
Python
but when I run the command :-->import mysql.connector
on idle I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
Can someone help me out (I am currently on macOS Bigsur )and new to such installations and setup
PLZ HELP

Comment: Please read any of the multiple duplicate questions that have answers.  Search [macos] or [python-idle] questions for `ModuleNotFoundError` or maybe just `ModuleNotFound`.

Comment: sir tried all of them but none worked If you could help